# How do I translate a folder/path name in Next.js 14 using basic translation system suggested within their doc?

Tags: next.js, middleware

I'm using their documentation method to translate the site, simple two languages for now, so I have the `src/app/[lang]/` structure and the `middleware.ts` inside `src`

This works fine for normal use cases, but what if I want to translate the path/folder before the dynamic page as for instance `/product/[slug]` (en) and `/produkt/[slug]` (de) ?

What I tried is to add some code within my **middleware.ts** as:

```
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/de/') && request.nextUrl.pathname.includes('product')) {
    const newUrl = url.pathname.replace('product', 'produkt')
    return NextResponse.rewrite(newUrl)
  }
```

but this throws an error:

> Error: URL is malformed "/de/produkt/1". Please use only
> absolute URLs -
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-relative-urls

tried their method of cloning the original url as:

```
if (request.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/de/') && request.nextUrl.pathname.includes('product')) {
    const url = request.nextUrl.clone()
    url.pathname = '/produkt'
    return NextResponse.rewrite(url)
  }
```

and the error is gone, but it does absolutely nothing.

So I tried also:

```
if (request.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/de/') && request.nextUrl.pathname.includes('product')) {
    const url = request.nextUrl.clone()
    const newUrl = url.pathname.replace('product', 'produkt')
    return NextResponse.rewrite(newUrl)
  }
```

but this also throws that error.

So that was the first question "how do I achieve something like that?"
second question would be "is it SEO friendly to translate the path like that via middleware, considering in my layout I generate static params for locales as they suggest in their doc as:

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return i18n.locales.map((locale) => ({ lang: locale }))
}
```

does this include the middleware translation? not specified in the doc.